# Finding hard to fit into right site between Super User and Web Applications

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This is addressed to the OP of [How to wrap lines of code in Rstudio IDE?](https://superuser.com/q/1772593/152004) in relation of the following comment

> I am lost. My questions are migrated between Super User and Applications back and forward. Is there a need to have so many stacks? It's hard to fit into the right one then.

I have seen your previous questions here in Super User. I leave comments on some of them. I found only one question migrated from Super User to Web Applications to one question from Web Applications to Super User.

I posted this question for your behalf and adding an answer here as well in order to help you understand how to find the right site for a question, specifically between Super User and Web Applications SE.

Comment: Also - OP might benefit from understanding that the web in web apps is important

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You are right... I assumed that "web" was involutarely omitted in the OP comment in the main site question, but few moments ago I migrated a new quesition and the [OP commented](https://superuser.com/questions/1772997/obs-studio-wont-record-audio-only#comment2763219_1772997) something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Tl;Dr: If your question is about an *application* that should be installed in your computer it might belong to Super User, if it is about an *application* that requires a **web browser** like Wikipedia and Youtube it might be ontopic in Web Applications while the question focus on the use of the *application*.

---

The best is that you read the on-topic page of each site

- Super User https://superuser.com/help/on-topic
- Web Applications https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Additional, recently I have posted a `faq` in Meta Web Applications
explaining the section of the [site tour](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) corresponding to the its scope: [Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4896/88163).

Quick hints:

1. Using Google Sheets, Wikipedia, Facebook, Gmail, Amazon and alike ([application software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software)) **using** a *desktop web browser* might be on-topic in [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com). This type of applications are known as *web applications*. They should not be confussed with desktop applications, mobile applications, IoT applications among others.

   One exception about the questions that might be asked in Web Applications SE are *troubleshooting like* questions.
2. Using Excel, Zoom Meeting, Slack and alike ([application software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_software)) **not** using a *desktop web browser* might be on-topic in Super User. This type of applications usually are referred as *desktop application* because they usually are accesed from the computer desktop.
3. Wordpress, Microsoft 365, Wayback Machine (archive.org), among others are specially tricky.

   - Questions about using the through a **web browser** might be asked in Web Applications
   - Questions about installing software, troubleshooing like questions might be on topic in Super User
   - For other types of questions, please ask for a site recommendation in [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)

---

#### Overlaping topics

There are some topics that might be specially tricky like **[spreadsheets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spreadsheet)** as there are certain similarities and compatibilities i.e. functions, formula syntax among the different types i.e. web and destop applications.

The typical comparision is Excel vs Google Sheets but it also could be done Excel (desktop) versus Excel Online (web). When asking questions about *spreadsheets* please be clear about what application and platform.

When mentioning an *application*, in general, use the name giving by the application developer, i.e. avoid using "excel" as synonym of spreadsheet, or "messenger" as synonym of instant messaging / chat application, instead use Excel, Google Sheets, LibreOffice, Skype, Google Chat, etc.

Regarding the platform the most popular are:

- Windows and Mac might be on topic in Super User.
- Web might be on topic in [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com).
- Android might be on topic in [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com).
- iOS might be on topic in [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

The complete list of Stack Exchange sites is in https://stackexchange.com/sites.

If you still are struggling to decide what is the proper site where to ask a question consider to ask for a site recommendation in [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com)