# How do I get my question reopened?

Tags: support, closed-questions

My [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1776749) was closed because it was not worded properly.

The helper box prompted me to edit my question but it is still closed.

I'm unable to find instructions on what to do next to get it reopened.

Comment: When you edited your question.  Did click the checkbox next to "This edit resolves the original close reason and the question should be considered for reopening."?  According history of your question, it has not been nominated to be reopened, thus it hasn't been reopened.  However, I agree with the answer you recieved, your question is not ready to be reopened.

Answer (score 5):

Editing isn't enough - the question still lacks clarity on what needs to be done.

So you have a template, sure but what's the data source? What do you want to fill up the files *with*? How do you want to name them?

Fundamentally, you need to help people help you to resolve your problem and the details that someone who knows the 'tools' needs to apply those skills to your problem.

Right now the problem isn't really defined at all.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: You need to make your question an on-topic,  practical, detailed question.

---

Super User is not a place for any kind of "question".

There are thousands of ways *to use a template to generate multiple files from it*, but it depend on several factors.

Your question doesn't include enough details for most of the factors. You practically are delegating to others several of the decisions and due to the lack of details there is a great chances that it will be required a lot of back a forth which this site is not intented to have.

If you don't have idea about *how to use a template to create 100+ files*, you should read a book, take a course, spend time doing tutorials, searching for related questions before asking a question, well, in this case, before editing again your question. Nowadays the Web have a lot of free resources related to what you are looking to do, even to learn to use Google and other search engines, an more recently ChatGPT became a hype, but be careful, trying to use a tool like ChatGPT without having idea about you will be chating with a tool that give looking feasible but wrong reponses besides making you lost time might make become confused and confuse others. Better look for reputable information and education sources.

Once you have a clear idea of how to do what you want to do, if you get stuck, review https://superuser.com/help/on-topic.

If your question is on topic, read carefully https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask. Then comeback and edit your question.

### Related

#### Super User Meta

- [Finding hard to fit into right site between Super User and Web Applications](https://meta.superuser.com/q/14924/152004)

#### Meta Stack Exchange

- [Is Stack Exchange supposed to be just for experts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121330/289691)
- [Where should a user post to ask for help bridging the knowledge / communication gap between experts in a field and themselves?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377949/289691)